# Why is eclipse showing compilation errors when my class is completely empty?

Tags: java, eclipse

My class currently looks like this:

```
package controller;

public class TestSprites {

}
```

When I try to run it, the console spits out this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on tokens, ( expected instead
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

at controller.TestSprites.<init>(TestSprites.java:55)
at controller.TestSprites.main(TestSprites.java:131)
```

I honestly have no idea what's going on. It was doing the same thing earlier when I actually had code in the class, so I took it all out, saved it, refreshed, exited and reopened eclipse. If it makes a difference, the code it was triggering on before was:

```
panel = new JPanel(){
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(SpriteObject j : sprites) {
        j.draw(g);
        }
    }
};
```

I also fail to see the issue there. Why is this happening, and how do I stop it?

Comment: That's not the class that has the compilation errors.  Look into `TestConvictSprites` instead.

Comment: Sorry, it's the same class but I renamed it in the interim, oops. Let me edit to make that clear.

Comment: Either your class is not empty or you have byte code enhancer that's modifying your compiled classes. According to the stack trace there is a main method: `at controller.TestSprites.main(TestSprites.java:131)`

Comment: If there is no static main method, Eclipse should not even try to run it (can't test that right now, but I seem to remember it). Does Eclipse pick another entry from the run menu? How do you actually "run" it?

Comment: You renamed the class? Then your Run configuration must still be looking for `main` in the old class.

Comment: I think @RealSkeptic might be right, I ended up just deleting the class and remaking it - now the original error's gone, and I'm getting "Error: Could not find or load main class controller.TestSprites"